# Decimal fields in Oracle external table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, external-tables

I build an external table in Oracle 12c using the following code

```
CREATE TABLE T_EXT_TABLE
(   
"ENTIDADE_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"ENTIDADE_AGE" NUMBER(*,0)
) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY "EXTTBL_DATA_DIRECTORY"
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    lrtrim
    (
         ENTIDADE_NAME 
        ,ENTIDADE_AGE
    )
  )
  LOCATION
  (
    'file.csv'
   )
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED 
PARALLEL 5 ;
```

And here's some data in my file.csv

```
PT;200;
PT;200.04;
```

I'd like to obtain an error in the 2nd record, since I have decimal places and the field in the external table is set as integer (number (*,0)). However, no matter how much I change the field definition in the external table, the record always gets selected, with the ENTIDADE_AGE field being rounded up.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: What do you get when you only does `"ENTIDADE_AGE" NUMBER`. Nothing you write for precision.

Comment: I wrote NUMBER(*,0) in the external table definition, which I assumed it would prevent decimal numbers from being selected... Also I've tried to write NUMBER(8,0) and still get the rounded result. I actually want the record to be rejected once there are decimal places.

Comment: Dont write precision. Just try with `"ENTIDADE_AGE" NUMBER`

Comment: If I don't write precision, both records will be selected as they are, i. e., 200 and 200.04

Comment: No this will not happen. Did you try that ?

Comment: I've tried the code above but removing the precision (*,0) and once I select from the external table I get both records, 200 and 200.04

Comment: If i create a table with column as number without precision and the try to insert 4.44 , it only allows 4 to get insert and same should happen with external table as well

Comment: If I write NUMBER, with no precision, the record will be selected showing only the integer part, leaving the decimal part out. But i actually want to obtain an error, I want the record to be rejected when it has a decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a NUMBER Format for a `CHAR` field in external table. It is only possible to define a `[date_format_spec][1]` (i.e. control the format of a `DATE` column)

You apparently can't use the `LOAD WHEN` to skip a number with decimal places as well, as only equal or not equal operators are allowed. (Not really sure as I didn't found
this in documentation, but I failed using `LIKE` )

What *should* be possible, is to set the decimal point character in a such way, that the conversion fails (in your case other than `.`) and the record will be rejected with

```
 ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Unfortunately you can't use `alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` as this is ignored in the external table.

In Oracle 12r2 there is a parameter `TERRITORY` that should serve this purpose. Try to set it to territory where the default decimal character is other than `.` This should work.
Tested fine in  12.2.0.1.0

Using this file

```
 PT;200
 PT;200.04
```

that has point as a decimal character you make define the expected decimal character in the external table with the TERRITORY parameter

```
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    TERRITORY AMERICA
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

For TERRITORY AMERICA both records are selected (as the number can be parsed)

```
ENTIDADE_NAME                                      ENTIDADE_AGE
-------------------------------------------------- ------------
PT                                                          200 
PT                                                       200,04
```

Now change the TERRITORY

```
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    TERRITORY GERMANY
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

For TERRITORY GERMANY (as en example where comma as a decimal character) only the first record is processed.
The second one is rejected as the number can't be parsed

```
ENTIDADE_NAME                                      ENTIDADE_AGE
-------------------------------------------------- ------------
PT                                                          200
```

Which is your expected behaviour.
In the log file you see

```
 ORA-01722: Ungültige Zahl
```

which is German for `ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The TERRITORY clause had occurred to me as well, but the thing is I have another column in the same external table which is a double, and which decimal part should be accepted. this makes it trickier.

Comment: @miduarte you can allways define the external table that accepts all rows wrapped with a trivial view that suppress the rows with non integer values.